# How to limit a search to posts on which I have commented

Tags: support

The scenario is as follows: ISTR a previous question on which I have commented that is relevant to a new question, so I search for the previous question using tags and likely search strings. I get a list of, say, twenty results that I then have to look at one by one and try to figure out whether it was the previous question (sometimes I can rule it out immediately, sometimes I have to click on it and check further).

Another way to go is go back through the list of questions on which I have commented, trying to find it that way. But I have managed to accumulate more than 100 pages of such comments, so that is generally inefficient, unless I'm sure the comment was recent.

Is there any way that I can say: "Use the intersection of the set of questions found using the first method (tags/search strings) and the set of questions found using the second method (questions I have commented on)" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in functionality for this; the only way I know of is using the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/). I've written [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/emacs/query/1310895/search-in-posts-with-comments-by-a-certain-user); it needs your user ID, which can be found in the URL to your profile page. It only allows a simple text search; feel free to fork the query if you need something more complicated like searching on tags.

[image]

SEDE is updated once a week, on Sunday morning, so really new posts won't end up there.

Comment: That was very helpful - thanks!